# How to return a string value from datatable in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting unable to store datatable value in string . How to return a string value of a data table? It gives an error while returning scalar value.

> An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code-- error in return statement

```
txtSalespersonName.Text = dl.GetStringValue("select top 1 [ContactPerson]  from tbl_Companies where Company='" +companyname + "' order by id desc");
public string GetStringValue(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KernelCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

      //  Response.Write(ex.Message);

    }
    return dt.Rows[1].ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code-- error in return statement

Comment: shouldn't it be `dt.Rows[0]` because it is the first element ?

Comment: ya i changed that . im getting  value like this - "System.Data.DataRow"

Comment: Correct, then you need to access the column to get the data `dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()` or `dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, error is occurring because `DataTable` is zero indexed based and your query is returning just 1 value thus it is out of range. `dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()` will give you correct output.

But Since you are returning a single value from the query, I would suggest you to use [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead like this:-

```
string ContactPerson = String.Empty;
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KernelCS"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con))
    {
        ContactPerson = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
}
return ContactPerson;
```

Also, use parametrized query to avoid [SQL Injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

`dt.Rows[1]` returns the second `DataRow` in your table which is not exist since your query returns *only* one row. You can use it as;

```
return dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

But don't use `SqlDataAdapter` if you only get one row. Use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar) which is *exactly* what this for.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
     cmd.CommandText = query;
     con.Open();
     return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();               
}
```

By the way, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.